# Program bluetooth receiver to only be pairable with a single device?

Tags: bluetooth

Is there a way to program a bluetooth receiver/dongle so it's only discoverable/accessible by a single device? This for security purposes as I can't switch on bluetooth on my pc but still want to use my bluetooth keyboard. I know some keyboards come with pre-programmed dongles that do exactly that. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Except you program on firmware, otherwise it is difficult to program the receiver/dongle.